# how to resolve Google cloud error for SDK installation on Windows 7

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After installation for google cloud while connecting to google cloud getting below error

Any one please let me know how to solve the issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDDiC.png)

I tried using with --no-browser not not resolved

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try using

```
gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser
```

That is authentication without opening web browser

Comment: Tried with "gcloud auth login --no-browser"        But not solved                                                                             ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication.
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) The provided authorization response is invalid. Expect a url with query parameters of [state, code, scope].